# How to pass an object from Java to JavaScript using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, rhino

I am working on a Java program where an object needs to have user-customization behavior for one function. I am implementing this using Mozilla Rhino, JavaScript and Java.

I cannot figure out how to take the already instantiated object and pass it to a pre-written script.

I have looked through many tutorials on Rhino, and none have given an example like this. Any advice or links would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579820/694469) to another question passes an object, `data`, from Java to Rhino Javascript.

I have no idea whether or not it works (well I suppose it does). Here are the relevant parts:

```
public static class data { 
   Double value = 1.0d;
}

ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName ("rhino"); 
data data = new data();
Context.enter().getWrapFactory().setJavaPrimitiveWrap(false);

engine.eval("function test(data) { return data.get('value1') + 5;};"); 
System.out.println("Result:" + ((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction("test", data));
```

(I didn't know about that `setJavaPrimitiveWrap()`, [here is some WrapFactory Javadoc](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/WrapFactory.html).)