# sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeJavaObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, javax.script

I'm using java 6 javax.script feature but I have an issue :

Before I call the ScriptEngine.eval() method I put some attributes to the ScriptContext:

```
scriptContext.setAttribute("Utils", utils, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
```

In the script I call :

```
var s = utils.getMyString()
```

The Java getMyString() method returns a String (java.lang.String).

The type of 's' in the scriptContext is sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeJavaObject that wrap the Java String instance.

When I try to get the attribute from the context in Java with:

```
(String) scriptContext.getAttribute("s");
```

I got

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException:
 sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeJavaObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

When I write in the script:

```
var s = "hello world"
```

or

```
var s = "" + utils.getMyString()
```

or

```
var s = String(utils.getMyString())
```

all is well because these are javascript Strings that can be get from the scriptContext thanks to an internal conversion.

I think that NativeJavaObjects should be unwrapped (see sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Wrapper.unwrap()) when they are released from the scriptContext.

So, is it a bug ? I have the same issue with java7u5.

I don't beleive that I would have to do :

```
var s = String(utils.getMyString())
```

to convert a Java String to a JavaScript String to be able to get it back as a Java String...

Thanks for your point of view.

Comment: The problem occurs for Strings.
If getMyString() returns MyString instance It works.
So why this issue for methods returning Strings ???

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814010/javascript-rhino-java-float-method-returns-number-or-object
and
[Rhino Javascript: How to convert Object to a Javascript primitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579777/rhino-javascript-how-to-convert-object-to-a-javascript-primitive)

but in your case I beleive that:

```
Context.enter().getWrapFactory().setJavaPrimitiveWrap(false);
```

will throw NullPointerException.
You use Rhino from JDK javax.script, and ScriptEngine.eval methods wrapps all operations handling context (enter, exit context etc), so if you invoke above-mentioned code before eval, rhino context may not be initialized (enter method assign context to current Thread).

Solution may be to use Rhino directly form org.mozilla and handling context directly: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial)
and invoke above code when enter a context.

I had similar problem (and others as well) when i used JDKs ScriptEngine and i solved it using Rhino form mozilla.